# Set debugging option in Gulp Karma test

Tags: javascript, gulp, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, gulp-karma

According to [this post](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/debugging-karma-unit-tests/) (and the general internet) if I want to run a Karma test without these kinds of code coverage commands...

```
__cov_9C0014nbzu2SxN3FICah6Q.f['35']++;
__cov_9C0014nbzu2SxN3FICah6Q.s['138']++;
```

...I simply need to set the `--debug` option in the terminal like so:

```
$ karma start karma.conf.js --browsers=Chrome --single-run=false --debug
```

However, when running your Karma tests via a Gulp task the documentation seems to be missing. I'm using a simply `karma.start` config object below. I've tried setting the `debug` property to either `true` or the strign `'--debug'`, however neither seems to have an effect (although the tests do run/the runner doesn't crash).

```
karma.start({
    configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js',
    exclude: excludeFiles,
    singleRun: !!singleRun,
    debug: '--debug'
}, karmaCompleted);
```

Any ideas how to set the debug option when running your Karma tests from a Gulp task?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting `debug: true` in the options object I pass to `karma.start` works just as well as using `--debug` at the command line. In other words, what you said you did in your Gulpfile works to get the `debug` option to Karma. However,

> I simply need to set the `--debug` option in the terminal like so

No, the page you link to shows that you **also need to customize your configuration to tweak the preprocessor list** so that when `--debug` is used the list is empty. The problem you have is consistent with having failed to perform that customization correctly.

Here is how the customization could be performed. This queries the value of `config.debug` from the configuration that Karma has already parsed from the command line:

```
module.exports = function configure(config) {
  config.set({
    // ...
    preprocessors: {
      "index.js": config.debug ? [] : ["coverage"],
    },
    // ...
  });
};
```

Scanning `process.argv` for `--debug` like suggested on the page you took the idea from won't work when you invoke Karma from Gulp because the `debug` option is passed directly through the configuration. Inspecting `config.debug` works both at the command line and  when Karma is invoked through it's programmatic API.